# Planarity testing given an embedding

Tags: algorithms, graphs, planar-graphs

I am given a connected graph $G$ with some embedding. I want to find a non-deterministic algorithm running in $O(n)$ time to decide whether $G$ with that embedding is a *plane graph* (i.e, can be drawn without intersecting edges).

I know there exist algorithms that decide whether a graph is planar or not in time $O(n)$, **but** they are not given a fixed embedding, and only check whether there exists an embedding in which the graph is planar or not.

I also know that there are $O(n\log n)$ time algorithms that compute the intersection points of lines, but since my input is a graph with an embedding, it is less "general" than finding the intersection of a set of lines, so I suspect there might be a faster algorithm here.

I would be glad if you could refer me to some sources about this problem, and if a solution exists I would like to know more about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asked on [so]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013516/how-to-certify-a-planar-embedding

Comment: Are those linear time algorithms?

Comment: You can read the answer on Stack Overflow as well as I can.